# The difference between 'painter' vs 'artist '

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the differences between
' painter ' and ' artist ' ?
I am so confused with it.

Comment: Related: http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/7533/230

Answer (score 1):

A painter is one who paints (anything, on anything). An artist is one who approaches solving a problem in a non-engineering, heuristic way (for sake of argument, I do realize some engineering solutions can be so beautiful as to be artistic)

A painter is an artist, one who paints signs is a commercial artist, but an artist may not be a painter. ie a sculptor

Without getting too philosophical, the person who makes your coffee might be considered an artist (in making coffee, not as an alternative occupation) in the same way as "beauty is in the eye of the beholder", depends what you think. But they would not be considered a painter.

Answer (score -1):

In general:

Artist. 
Root -> Art (Arts) people who do 'Arts'. It may be performing Arts (i.e., theatre, music, dance), visual arts (i.e., painting, sculpting, multimedia), or combination.

Painter. 
Root -> paint. A person who makes paintings.

Comment: A painter might not be creating a work of art - the word *painter* is used to describe someone painting the exterior of a house, for example, while if an artist did that, we'd be expecting the side of the house to have a pretty picture on it.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Take note that I mentioned 'in general', considering that both words the post provided lead to some confusion regarding some arts-related matter, presumably. Thank you for your comment - disambiguation.